# object as member variable

Tags: c++, class, object

hi i have faced an issue while accessing an object,

in my program there are 2 classes class A and B

class b has a member variable name, which kepts as private.and gettes/setter functions to access this variable(bcoz the variable is private).

in Class A, has a member variable , object of class B b(private).And i have used a getter to get this object outside the class.

now i want to set the name of object b using the object of class a.
so created the following code, but i didnot working.

please help me to solve this.

```
     // GetObject.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
   //

   #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <iostream>

  class B
 {
   int name;
   public:
   int getname()
   {
     return name;
   }
   void SetName(int i)
   {
     name = i;
   }
  };
  class A
  {
   private:
   B b;
   public:

   B GetB()
   {
      return b;
   }

   };


   int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
   {
   int ii = 10;
  A a;
  a.GetB().SetName(ii);
  std::cout<<" Value :"<<a.GetB().getname();
  getchar();
return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the member by reference (or pointer):

```
B& GetB()
{
   return b;
}
//or
B* GetB() //i'd prefer return by reference
{
   return &b; 
}
```

The way you have it now, you're returning a copy of the object.

So `B A::GetB()` doesn't return the original object. Any changes you make on it will not affect the member of `a`. If your return by reference, a copy is not created. You would be returning the exact `B` object that is a member of `a`.